# Wordpress on a second volume

Tags: linux, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I have a complex Wordpress multisite that is difficult to migrate to another server. I need to upgrade the underlying OS from AWS Linux to AWS Linux 2 for security reasons. Since upgrading the OS on the EC2 instance is not an option, is it possible to create a new AWS EC2 instance running AWS Linux 2 and attach a copy of the existing Wordpress volume to the new AWS Linux 2 instance and run Wordpress from the new instance? This would allow me to update SSL/TLS/PHP to more secure versions without having to recreate the complex configuration of the existing site on another machine.

Comment: It is certainly possible in theory.

Comment: You might want to ask this on: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can take an [EBS snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html) of original Amazon Linux instance, then [create a volume from the snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-volume.html#ebs-create-volume-from-snapshot) and attach that volume to the new Amazon Linux 2 instance. The volume will have all the existing Wordpress data from the Amazon Linux system.